# Clear scroll request using JavaScript client (Not use client helpers )

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I could not get an API to clear scroll request in JavaScript client. I am fetching data recursively using scroll API and I want clear scroll request if user switches to another tab.

I am using doc here => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/master/scroll_examples.html

To fetch at start

```js
await client.search({
    index: 'my index',
    scroll: '300s',
    size: 500,
    query: {
      match_all: {}
    }
  })
```

To fetch using scroll it next time

```js
await client.scroll({
        scrollId: body._scroll_id,
        scroll: '30s'
      })
```

At the end, I want clear scroll request and I haven't found that in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clearScroll` for clearning scroll using specific id.

```js
await client.clearScroll({
        scrollId: body._scroll_id
      })
```

You can check [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/master/api-reference.html#_clear_scroll) documentation.